# How to include triggered record to my logic?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 2 custom objects: Game__c and Bet__c. I need to create trigger in which the system should calculate Game Rating based on the Total Money Bet (more money means higher rating).

TotalMoneyBet__c - its Roll-up Summary filed on Game__c (sum Amount__c on Bet__c)

Every time a new bet is created, recalculate and set the rating: max totalmoneybet = gamerating 1

I've write a code and its working but not include triggered bet. Can you help me with this issue?

```
public class CalculateGameRatingTriggerHandler {
    public static void beforeUpdate(Game__c[] updatedGames) {
        Game__c[] topTenGames = [SELECT TotalMoneyBet__c FROM Game__c ORDER BY TotalMoneyBet__c DESC LIMIT 10];
        Id[] topTenGameIds = new Id[0];
        for(Game__c gameRecord: topTenGames) {
            topTenGameIds.add(gameRecord.Id);
        }
        for(Integer index = 0, size = updatedGames.size(); index < size; index++) {
            Integer gamePosition = topTenGameIds.indexOf(updatedGames[index].Id);
            if(gamePosition != -1) {
                updatedGames[index].GameRating__c = 1 + gamePosition;
            } else {
                updatedGames[index].GameRating__c = null;
            }
        }
        //update topTenGames;
        Game__c[] notTopTenGames = [SELECT Id FROM Game__c WHERE Id NOT IN :topTenGames AND ID NOT IN :updatedGames AND GameRating__c > 0];
        for(Game__c gameRecord: notTopTenGames) {
            gameRecord.GameRating__c = null;
        }
        update notTopTenGames;
    }
}

trigger GameTrigger on Game__c (before update) {
    CalculateGameRatingTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(trigger.new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that rollup summary fields are calculated *after* the after insert/update triggers, so those values aren't incorrect if you query them now. Instead, put this in a `before update` trigger on the Game__c object.

```
public class CalculateGameRatingTriggerHandler {
    public static void beforeUpdate(Game__c[] updatedGames) {
        Game__c[] topTenGames = [SELECT TotalMoneyBet__c FROM Game__c ORDER BY TotalMoneyBet__c DESC LIMIT 10];
        Id[] topTenGameIds = new Id[0];
        for(Game__c gameRecord: topTenGames) {
            topTenGameIds.add(gameRecord.Id);
        }
        for(Integer index = 0, size = updatedGames.size(); index < size; index++) {
            Integer gamePosition = topTenGameIds.indexOf(updatedGames[index].Id);
            if(gamePosition != -1) {
                updatedGames[index].GameRating__c = 1 + gamePosition;
            } else {
                updatedGames[index].GameRating__c = null;
            }
        }
        Game__c[] notTopTenGames = [SELECT Id FROM Game__c WHERE Id NOT IN :topTenGames AND ID NOT IN :updatedGames AND GameRating__c > 0];
        for(Game__c gameRecord: notTopTenGames) {
            gameRecord.GameRating__c = null;
        }
        update notTopTenGames;
    }
}
```

Note that technically some recursion happens here, but it will never recurse more than once, so we don't need to worry about "blocking" it in most cases.

Comment: thats not working, top10 games not updating. and if I add update topTenGames method i get error self_reference_from_trigger

Comment: @АндрейЛукиенко Without seeing the trigger as well, I cannot further help you at this time. If you edit your question to include the new logic, I will take a look at it today for you. Please include both the class and trigger.

Comment: first post was updated

Comment: could you please look at trigger? Thanks